# Conditional ? : operator with class constructor

Tags: c++, c++14, conditional-operator

could someone explain me why `c` and `c1` are constructed different way.
I understand that I have reference to copy created by '?' operator, which is destroyed after construction, but why in first case it behave other way.
I've tested if its optimization, but even with conditions read from console, I have  same result. Thanks in advance

```
#include <vector>

class foo {
public:
    foo(const std::vector<int>& var) :var{ var } {};
    const std::vector<int> & var;
};

std::vector<int> f(){
    std::vector<int> x{ 1,2,3,4,5 };
    return x;
};

int main(){
    std::vector<int> x1{ 1,2,3,4,5 ,7 };
    std::vector<int> x2{ 1,2,3,4,5 ,6 };
    foo c{ true ? x2 : x1 };    //c.var has expected values 
    foo c1{ true ? x2 : f() };  //c.var empty 
    foo c2{ false ? x2 : f() };  //c.var empty 
    foo c3{ x2 };  //c.var has expected values
}
```

Answer (score 21):

The type of a *conditional expression* is the *common type* of the two branches, and its *value category* also depends on them.

- For `true ? x2 : x1`, the *common type* is `std::vector<int>` and the *value category* is **lvalue**. This can be tested with:

  ```
  static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype((true ? x2 : x1)),  std::vector<int>&>);
  ```
- For `true ? x2 : f()`, the *common type* is `std::vector<int>`, and the *value category* is **prvalue**. This can be tested with:

  ```
  static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype((true ? x2 : f())),  std::vector<int>>);
  ```

Therefore you are storing a dangling reference in `c1`. Any access to `c1.var` is **undefined behavior**.

[**live example on godbolt.org**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/AorDKD)

Comment: ...resulting in UB, **if** it is accessed after the declaration. That crucial part was omitted from OP's example though.

Comment: It'd be good to explain why these are the common types (ie: because the second case involves an lvalue and prvalue, while the first case is two lvalues).

Comment: Oh C++. Oh you.

Comment: Don't conflate an expression's type with its value category. A `?:` never has reference type. Not even the adjusted-away-prior-to-any-further-analysis one.

Comment: @T.C.: updated the answer, please let me know if it's correct now.